# Реализация хранения иерархических отчетов Java + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть задача хранения в базе данных отчетов, заранее структура показателей неизвестна. Но отчеты имеют вид похожий на бухгалтерские, типа: Отчет о прибылях или убытках и Бухгалтерский баланс. Но показатели могут задаваться пользователем, например в одном отчете о прибылях или убытках будет прибыль от курсовых разниц, а в другом нет. Порядок показателей может быть разный.

Соответственно, если прибыли и убытки можно представить в виде плоского отчета, то Баланс желательно в виде иерархической структуры.

Есть какие нибудь примеры реализаций объектов в Java и как реализовать хранение таких отчетов в БД используя Hibernate? Не знаю с чего начать.

Comment: В БД правильно хранить данные для генерации, а не сами отчеты

Comment: если у вас есть гора документов и вам обязательно их хранить, то может посмотреть в сторону нереляционной бд типа монго?

Comment: А для того, чтобы перейти с PostgresSQL на MongoDB в коде Java(Spring) потребуется только поменять у репозитариев JPARepository на MongoRepository? Или там много различий и нюансов?